# PM2: Is it possible to stop a process when there are no requests

Tags: node.js, heroku, process, pm2

The way Heroku works, when there are no more web requests to a free dyno for `x min` it stops the app, and starts again when the first request comes in.

**Question:** Is there any way using PM2 to setup Heroku like nodejs processes which stops when there are no requests for 30 mins and starts on hitting the first request? (If not, how can I built this)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with stopping the process?

Comment: I have some apps to run which are very low traffic.. to make optimum use of memory i wanted to try this. Apps which idle should be stopped and started again when needed.